# How to store results of sql query with column name as dictionary in python?

Tags: python, sql, dictionary

Suppose I have a query such as the following which returns only a ***single row***:

```
SELECT name, age, height, weight
FROM my_bio
```

I want to store the result of this query as a dictionary like the following:

```
SQLdict = {'name': 'eric', 'age': 27, 'height': '5.9', 'weight': '99'}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to your database?

Comment: @mgilson I'm using MySQLdb

Answer (score 0):

Use `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` for getting the result as dict:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

database = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "user", 
                           passwd = "password", db = "mydb",
                           cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
c = database.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT name, age, height, weight FROM my_bio")
row = c.fetchone()

print row['name']
```